FFMPEG convert RTSP to MPEG-TS with constant size packets
I have an RTSP stream which I want to convert, via FFMPEG, to an MPEG-TS stream with constant size UDP packets. I have played around with many FFMPEG options and the closest one I've found so far is this:
ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost:123 -f rtp_mpegts udp://localhost:456
This produces a stream of packets of size 1328, which is equivalent to 7 MPEG-TS packets (188 bytes each) plus a 12-byte RTP header. However, I don't want to have an RTP header. I could remove this programmatically but I'd rather figure out how to get FFMPEG to do it properly.
I haven't been able to find a combination of options which results in constant-size packets with the -f mpegts option. How do I tell the muxer how many MPEG-TS packets I want in each UDP packet?
ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost:123 -f rtp_mpegts udp://localhost:456 -> packets with Len=1328
ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost:123 -f mpegts udp://localhost:456?pkt_size=1316 -> packets with lengths from 220-1348 (1-7 MPEG-TS packets)

According to the following post, for fixed packet size, we should add -flush_packets 0:
ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost:123 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://localhost:456?pkt_size=1316

I tested using synthetic video with Windows 10.
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=30 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://localhost:456?pkt_size=1316
Wireshark shows that the packet size is 1368 with the above command.
When using IP address:
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=30 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://127.0.0.1:456?pkt_size=1316
Wireshark shows that the packet size is 1348 bytes.
